# Removing Duplicate Contacts from Tracking Extracts

Tags: subscriber-key, duplicate-value, tracking-extract

We had a new member of our team accidentally map the wrong SubscriberKey which ended up creating ~500k duplicate contacts. We work with another vendor who ingests the tracking extracts for future reporting. Is there anyway to update those extracts and reassign with correct SubsriberKey?